# Sql Server Query for getting result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table schema as following

```
id    pid   amount   drcr    residce  
1     33    1000         1        55  
2     32    2000         2        44  
3     33    1500         2        54
```

Here I  want to calculate sum with `drcr` returns value whose value is  greater 
for ex. here  `1500 > 100`  so it should return `total = 500` , `drcr = 2` for `pid  = 33`
I  tried  googling stuff but not got any idea.

Comment: your requirement is not clear to me. could you please describe the use of drcr and also the desired output as per the given data?

Comment: Thanks for  very quick response here  drcr  is debit or credit .For instance where  pid  =33  .There are   two amounts . I want to calucate the sum of amount where drcr =1 and sum where drcr =2 and return the difference with drcr if cr amount is greater then cr .if dr is greater then dr.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for conditional aggregation as

```
SELECT pid, SUM(CASE WHEN drcr = 2 THEN Amount ELSE -Amount END) 
FROM
(
  VALUES
  (1,     33,    1000,         1,        55),  
  (2,     32,    2000,         2,        44),  
  (3,     33,    1500,         2,        54)
) T(id, pid, amount, drcr, residce)
GROUP BY pid
```

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f5f1569bbdca96216042762d96ed6c64)